# Why do I get different output when entering the same string in a prompt vs passing it as a variable?

Tags: powershell

Can someone explain to me why I am seeing different output when I enter the same string one entered when prompted by powershell and the other when I pass by a variable. I would like to know how I need to format the string when entering it in the prompt to produce the same output that I get when I pass it as a variable.

**test.ps1**

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $NewArgumentString
)

$NewArguments = (Write-Output $NewArgumentString | ConvertFrom-StringData)
$NewArguments
```

Run:

```
PS> $testString = "HOSTNAME = jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1"
PS> .\test.ps1 -NewArgumentString $testString

Name                           Value
----                           -----
HOSTNAME                       jburns-test
IP                             127.0.0.1


PS> .\test.ps1

cmdlet a.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
NewArgumentString: HOSTNAME = jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
HOSTNAME                       jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1
```

[image]

Comment: my understanding is that - unless you provide a template - each `key = value` pair must be on a line of it's own. it looks like that escaped newline aint being expanded as such.

Comment: That is true but in my local testing I was able to achieve this with an escaped new line, I will edit the question to show that.

Comment: how odd. i tested a stripped down function with your code and it works in both the ISE and the console. my environment is win7x64, ps5.1. ///// i recommend you post a sanitized example that shows the problem. ///// it works properly when i call it from a script, also.

Comment: Did you accidentally write "`n" as "``n"?

Comment: or have you enclosed the string in single quotes?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Updated with a paired down script

Comment: @Buster - kool! now, when i run your code with the [now missing] sample input, i see your problem. however, MY version used `$NewArguments = $NewArgumentString | ConvertFrom-StringData` while your version uses `$NewArguments = (Write-Output $NewArgumentString | ConvertFrom-StringData)` ///// the problem may be either the `()` or the `Write-Output`.

Comment: Wanted to streamline the question so I removed all the unnecessary info, just tested with `$NewArguments = $NewArgumentString | ConvertFrom-StringData` and had the same results as the screenshot in the question. Now that I know it works when passing as a variable that is how I will use this script anyways to I am not blocked but I am still curious as to why it behaves this way.

Comment: @Buster - good that you have it working ... as for why your method failed - i have no ideas. [*sigh ...*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this code responds differently to the prompt vs passing in a variable is because we are dealing with the difference between *interpreted* strings vs. *literal* strings. a.k.a. single quotes vs. double quotes.

Strings at the prompt are treated like literal strings, and not interpreted strings. That's why at the prompt you can't reference variables. To demonstrate the different effect this has with the example, let's run through it where we swap out the double quotes for single quotes in the passed variable, to emulate writing in the string at the prompt:

```
PS> $testString = "HOSTNAME = jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1"
PS> $testString2 = 'HOSTNAME = jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1'

PS> .\test.ps1 -NewArgumentString $testString

Name                           Value
----                           -----
HOSTNAME                       jburns-test
IP                             127.0.0.1


PS> .\test.ps1 -NewArgumentString $testString2

Name                           Value
----                           -----
HOSTNAME                       jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1
```

Here we see confirmation that the literal single quoted string is interpreted the same as the prompt is. What *Really* is going on is that the two strings are not the same. For the first double quoted string, immediately after the assignment, PowerShell converts the two character combination "`n" (0x96 + 0x6E) into the single Line Feed "LF" (0x0A) character. We can see this by comparing the string lengths:

```
PS> $testString = "HOSTNAME = jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1"
PS> $testString.Length
37

PS> $testString2 = 'HOSTNAME = jburns-test`nIP = 127.0.0.1'
PS> $testString2.Length
38
```

To truly replicate the results of our theory in the example, let's enter into the prompt the -same- "bitwise" string that is stored in the variable by replacing `n with the non printable LF character (only possible by using the [ALT + numpad](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0) method) ALT + 0010

```
PS> .\test.ps1

cmdlet a.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
NewArgumentString: HOSTNAME = jburns-test
IP = 127.0.0.1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
HOSTNAME                       jburns-test
IP                             127.0.0.1
```

And voila! We have replicated the results. PowerShell is not broken. Our faith in functions and parameter passing is restored!

---

As an aside, it's probably not recommended to pass strings into your functions and rely on the function to convert it into a hash table, as that can give, as you have demonstrated, unpredictable results. I would instead directly pass in a [Hash Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) (Type `[hashtable]`) right into the function:

**testHashTable.ps1**

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [hashtable]
    $MyHashTable
)

Write-Output $MyHashTable
```

```
PS> $testHashTable = @{ "HOSTNAME" = "jburns-test" ; "IP" = "127.0.0.1" }
PS> .\test.ps1 -MyHashTable $testHashTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
IP                             127.0.0.1
HOSTNAME                       jburns-test
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete, clear response this makes sense. After talking with a coworker we came to the similar conclusion, thinking that a user would expect what they typed in a prompt to be treated literally and not accidentally interpolated. And yes I think passing by a hashtable is smarter I thought at the time that I would have to deal with a string from the caller side but there is another way.